# Let $f$ be a harmonic function. Prove that $\overline{f}$ is harmonic.

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

Let $f$ be a harmonic function. Prove that $\overline{f}$ is harmonic.

I need help to write a rigorous proof. Thank you

Comment: What definition are you using for "harmonic"? Can you show that $\overline{f}$ satisfies those conditions if $f$ does?

Comment: f(x,y)= u(x,y) + iv(x,y) if f is harmonic then $f_{xx}$ +$f_{yy}$=0

Comment: OK, so try calculating $\overline{f}_{xx} + \overline{f}_{yy}$, since you know that $\overline{f}(x,y) = u(x,y) - iv(x,y)$.

Comment: @yagmour: that is not the definition... It is exactly backwards: **if** $f_{xx}+f_{yy}=0$, **then** $f$ is (by definition) harmonic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $f_{xx}=\partial_{xx} u(x,y)+i\partial_{xx}v(x,y)$ and the same for the derivative in $y$, hence $\Delta f(x,y)=\Delta u(x,y)+i\Delta v(x,y)$. As $u$ and $v$ admit *real* values, so does $\Delta u$ and $\Delta v$, hence $\Delta u=0=\Delta v$.

As $\Delta\bar f(x,y)=\Delta u(x,y)-i\Delta v(x,y)$, we get that $\bar f$ is harmonic if (and only if) so is $f$.